# How can I create an animation such as the one linked but with 2 images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wanting to create a loading animation out of 2 images in the same format as this gif.

http://preloaders.net/preloaders/298/Pie%20chart.gif

Where one image is the background and the other image circle fades on top of the background.

I have done some searching but I cannot seem to find what I am looking for. I'm using xcode and objective C just as a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you want to do a loading animation as shown using just 2 images?

I don't think that is possible. Especially for a smooth animation. You would need 720 images, one for each dark degree and one for each light degree. But if that is what you are looking for. UIImageView has some animation API's built in.

Add all the animation frames into an array and then set that array to the animationImages property of your UIImageView:

> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *animationImages

You can then set the duration for an animation lifecycle using the animationDuration property:

> @property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval animationDuration
>   Discussion
>   The time duration is measured in seconds. The default value of this property is equal to the number of images multiplied by 1/30th of a second. Thus, if you had 30 images, the value would be 1 second.

Whilst I doubt it is necessary in this this case you can set how many times the animation should repeat (0 is an infinite repeat)

> @property(nonatomic) NSInteger animationRepeatCount
>   Discussion
>   The default value is 0, which specifies to repeat the animation indefinitely.

Then you can simply call animateImages on the UIImageView e.g.

```
[myImageView startAnimating];
```

When you don't need the image any more, call the stopAnimating method.

```
[myImageView stopAnimating];
```

Then remove the imageView and release resources as normal.